# How to add two SUMs

Tags: mysql, sql

Why wont the following work?

```
SELECT SUM(startUserThreads.newForStartUser)+SUM(endUserThreads.newForEndUser) AS numNew ...
```

It returns an empty string.

The following is returning 1 for my data set however:

```
SELECT SUM(startUserThreads.newForStartUser) AS numNew ...
```

How do I add the two sums correctly?

The whole thing:

```
SELECT t.*,
       COUNT(startUserThreads.id) + COUNT(endUserThreads.id)                     AS numThreads,
       SUM(startUserThreads.newForStartUser) + SUM(endUserThreads.newForEndUser) AS numNew
FROM   `folder` `t`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `thread` `startUserThreads`
         ON ( `startUserThreads`.`startUserFolder_id` = `t`.`id` )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `thread` `endUserThreads`
         ON ( `endUserThreads`.`endUserFolder_id` = `t`.`id` )
WHERE  user_id = :user
```

FYI, only two users can share a thread in my model.  That should explain my column names

Comment: Can you show us the whole query?

Comment: Neither of your queries are valid.

Comment: added whole query. How is it not valid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(startUserThreads.newForStartUser),0)+COALESCE(SUM(endUserThreads.newForEndUser),0) AS numNew ...
```

Comment: It works.. but I don't get it.. We only give COALESCE one argument?

Comment: sorry second argument should be 0

Comment: ah cuz it trying to be adding an empty string to an integer!

Comment: realy it is a null not an empty string, sum only returns numeric values. so null + numeric yields null

Answer (score 1):

From the MySQL docs

> SUM([DISTINCT] expr)
>
> Returns the sum of expr. If the return set has no rows, SUM() returns
>   NULL. The DISTINCT keyword can be used in MySQL 5.0 to sum only the
>   distinct values of expr.
>
> SUM() returns NULL if there were no matching rows.
>
> Aggregate (summary) functions such as COUNT(), MIN(), and SUM() ignore
>   NULL values. The exception to this is COUNT(*), which counts rows and
>   not individual column values.

Maybe try COALESCE( SUM(x), 0 ) +  COALESCE( SUM(y), 0 )?

Comment: i thought sum will aggregate out nulls?